# Check if app is executed by another

Tags: android, android-intent, launch

I want to know if my app was executed by another app

I tried several methods but I could not find a solution

I tried this but returns the same value please help me! Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static boolean isinint;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // check if any application has executed your app
        if (intent != null && intent.getType() != null) {
            isinint = true; 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "is:" + isinint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            isinint = false; 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "is:" + isinint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiating between an Activity launch from home screen or from another activity from App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637876/differentiating-between-an-activity-launch-from-home-screen-or-from-another-acti)

Comment: not is a duplicate does not solve any problem

Comment: did u try the solution? if yes what r the values displayed

Comment: how about when you launch an activity yourself pass data to your intent, when your activity is launched by another app you can check that data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i check if an app running in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer from dhaval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213851/456814) will work for you

> Try this code:
>
> ```
>       ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
>          List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
>          for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
>          {
>              if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser")) 
>              {
>                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>              }
>          }
> ```

replace com.android.browser with your app process name.