# Get application launch method

Tags: android, firebase

I need to know, in the Application context, what launched my app (specifically, was it a natural launch -click on icon-, was it launched by a third partie app or through deep link, or was it from a Firebase push).
Is there a way to know that ?

Comment: Related.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637876/differentiating-between-an-activity-launch-from-home-screen-or-from-another-acti

Comment: Not really, getIntent() is not accessible in the Application class.

Comment: Ah, well, the Application class doesn't handle the starting of any particular Activity. You can't get any Intent filters from it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to know that ?

No.

> I need to know, in the Application context, what launched my app

Then IMHO you have put too much in the `Application` context. You are going to need to find some way of pushing the scenario-dependent logic into appropriate scenario-dependent entry points.

Comment: Well, I am creating an SDK and I wanted to initialize it in the Application class (as I seen other SDK do), but I think i'll do it in the launcher activity if I can't.